# Codeigniter redirect to variable url

Tags: codeigniter, variables, url, redirect

I'm working on a project in codeigniter. What I have done until now is that if you type for instance

```
http://localhost/ci_project/dashboard
```

it will redirect to a page called: restricted.
However, what I want to do is that when you type dashboard on the url, codeigniter will redirect to login controller. If the login is successfull, go to the dashboard or whatever controller that the user added into the URL.

Basically the idea is to get a variable from the URL given by the user.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the redirect function to send your users to any page you like:

`redirect($URL, 'refresh')`;

You can read more about this function here (at the bottom of the page:)

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Place an if statement in the target controller function (I'm assuming the index() function of the Dashboard class) to test if the user is logged in, then redirect as needed.